# UML association at programming level

Tags: associations, uml

Is there a corresponding representation in programming language such as java for the following sentence :
`Arrow on both ends means bidirectional relation, where both classes know about each other`?

and exactly `classes know about each other`?

Answer (score 1):

"Know about each other" means that objects of each class participating in the relationship hold reference(s) to their related parties.  e.g.:(*)

```
class Dog {
  private Person owner;
}

class Person {
  private Dog[] dogs;
}
```

That would correspond to a 1:Many Association among People and Dogs:

- Each Person owns Many Dogs (might be none if Dog array empty)
- Each Dog is owned by at most one Person (might not have an owner if `owner` is null).

Note that bi-directionality means the write accessors have to ensure consistency at both ends.  So, for example, `Dog.setOwner()` would also have to ensure that `Person.dogs` was correctly updated (by calling appropriate methods on Dog).  That's the price you pay for bi-directional navigation.

If you don't need navigation both ways you can remove one of the references.  For example:

```
class Dog {
  //no reference to owner
}

class Person {
  private Dog[] dogs;
}
```

In this example it's not possible to navigate from a Dog to its owner: but the write accessors for Person.dogs are correspondingly simpler.

hth.

--

(*) Note this is the defacto way to implement associations.  There is another way: declare the relationship as a class itself.  This is much less used - although can be handy for Association Classes where there are attributes of the Association itself; e.g.

```
class DogOwnership {
  private Person owner;
  private Dog dog;
  private License license; // license for this Person owning this Dog
}
```

The same rules apply on bi-directional access however.